I'm not quite sure I understand this daily puzzle on Lichess (9/6/24)
So I am attempting to solve the 9/6/24 daily puzzle on Lichess right now:
[Fen ""]
[Title "Black wins"]
[Startply "37"]

1.d4 Nf6 2.c4 g6 3.Nc3 d5 4.e3 Bg7 5.cxd5 Nxd5 6.Nxd5 Qxd5 7.Ne2 O-O 8.Nc3 Qd6
9.Be2 c5 10.Ne4 Qc6 11.Nxc5 Qxg2 12.Bf3 Qh3 13.Nxb7 Nd7 14.Na5 Rb8 15.Nc6 Rb6
16.Nxe7+ Kh8 17.Nd5 Re6 18.Nf4 Qf5 19.Bg4

This is from a rated 2+1 Bullet game between IM amrsobh (2198) - selfbrain (2203).
I am doubtful about whether or not I know the premise of this puzzle (although I believe it is supposed to be "Mate in X amount of moves"), and I'm not so sure about finding the solution to it.
My first thought was that if I play 19. ... Qa5, then White can play 20. Bd2 and it doesn't matter if I then attempt to play either 20. ... Rxe3 or 20. ... Ba6 since White can just block using 21. Qe2.

This also would happen if I tried to play 19. ... Rxe3 (White could just play 20. Bxe3 and then I wouldn't be able to make do optimally with just the Queen and Bishop)

So therefore I first would have to do 19. ... Ba6. This is because White now is unable to play 20. Kf1 without putting the king in check. Also:

I believe that White should then play 20. Be2 because that would lead to (assuming White forgets about the pawn on f2) 20. ... Bxe2 21. Qxe2 Qa5+ 22. Qd2 Rxe3+

However, I'm not exactly sure what could be done from here, so my question is:

Am I overthinking this puzzle, and if so, what's the intended solution to this?


Seems Black should just play 19. ... Qxf4;
White can't recapture because the Re6 pins the White e-pawn.
White will reply 20. Bxe6, grabbing a Rook while also putting
the bQf4 en prise.  But Black retorts 20. ... Qe4,
forking the Be6 and Rh1; White does best to defend this Rook and
let the Be6 go, so Black ends up winning B+N for R.
(If 21. Bxd7? Qxh1+ followed by trading Queens on d1
and recapturing on d7, winning a whole piece.)
Several of your variations let White capture the Black Queen
or Rook for almost nothing; for example 19. ... Ba6? 20. Bxf5 or
19. ... Qa5+ 20. Bd2 Ba6? 21. Bxa5.
